# How do you call one part of a pitched roof

Tags: single-word-requests

The pitched roof consists of two sloping sides that have some angle between them. So how would one call such a side?

I would like to replace `side of the roof` in the following sentence with one word:
"There is a chimney on one *side of the roof* and a dormer on another"

Comment: Generally, *roof;* or *slope* or *tiles.* It depends on how you're using the word. Could you edit your question to include the sentence you want this word to appear in?

Comment: A roof with (usually) two sloping sides is called a _pitched_ roof.

Comment: Thanks for comments - edited the question

Comment: What is wrong with side? That is what it is called. "The roof has a chimney on one side and a dormer on the opposite side."

Comment: @Damila Nothing wrong with it - I'm just not sure what the most appropriate word is.

Comment: I am not aware of any specific word. You can call it the slope instead of the side. There are names for every other  part of the pitched roof- ridge, hip, eave, soffit- and names fro each layer, but nothing specific for the side,

Comment: @Damila ok then! That answers my question. Would you post the answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Side or Slope**

A pitched roof has names for many parts, and names for each layer of the roof. The big wide part that would be called a side does not have any more specific name. It is called a side or a slope.

In your sentence:

The roof has a chimney on one side and a dormer on another.
The roof has a chimney on one slope and a dormer on another.

See here for an example:
https://www.caaquebec.com/en/at-home/guides/reshingling-your-roof/identifying-the-parts-of-the-roof-and-understanding-their-functions/